# Is it posible to integrate $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2}{n}\sin(nx)$ term to term when $x \in [-\pi,\pi]$?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, fourier-series

Let  $f(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2}{n}\sin(nx)$. I want to calculate its integral. Can I integral it term to term?

$\displaystyle\int\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2}{n}\sin(nx)dx=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int[(-1)^{n+1}\frac{2}{n}\sin(nx)]dx$

$x\in[-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: Yes because its partial sums are uniformly bounded

Comment: @Conrad how can I prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Dirichlet's theorem to prove the series uniformly convergence. Futhermore, each term integrable. Thus, you can integral it term to term.

Comment: And do you know if it is posible to derivate ir term to term? i.e:
$(\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac {2}{n}\sin(nx))'=\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}((-1)^{n+1}\frac {2}{n}\sin(nx))'$

When $x\in [-\pi,\pi]$

Comment: No. Can't. In your right hand side divergence.

Comment: The series is not uniformly convergent on $[-\pi,\pi]$ only on $[-\pi+a, \pi-a]$ as the limit is not continuous at the ends (it is $x/2$ which jumps there); of course one cannot differentiate term by term as the result is divergent; however one can "differentiate" in a generalized sense as the result of the differentiation is summable (but not convergent) to $1/2$ which is the derivative of the LHS except at the ends